# Jquery Mobile Setting Dynamic <body> HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having an issue with dynamically setting the data for the body tag when using Jquery Mobile. The goal of my little test is to save the state of a page, and then be able to go back to that state. I can do this easily by grabbing the html with...

```
$('body').html();
```

and

```
$('body').html('Store html');
```

My issue is that I'm using Jquery Mobile and the mobile widgets are displaying, but not functioning. I attempted to use...

```
$('body').trigger('create');
```

and

```
$('body').enhanceWithin();
```

These are creating new elements THAT WORK, but on top of Jquery Mobile elements that don't work. The non working elements were loaded from $('body').html().

How can I prevent the duplication of Jquery Mobile elements, and get functioning elements?

Comment: Rather than storing the entire HTML, you should just store the field values that a user can change and then restore those values when you go back to the page.

Comment: That's one possible solution, but that seems like it would be tedious to maintain. Especially if the state is kept for each page. I'm trying to NOT do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can store ALL the attributes for each element when saving state, and vice versa when loading state.